# Text compressing - Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, huffman-code, emu8086, text-compression

My mission is to basically compress a file, compress data (just alphabet letters without even space) in assembly. 
What I've done so far:
*Received all the data from the txt file
*Put it in an array in the following order: the letter with the most frequency is first, and so on.
*Put the frequency of each letter in the same order as before. For example:
a  b c
25 3 1
I wrote all of it in emu8086 EXE template. I can link the code if anyone's interested but I don't think that's relevent.

Now I have to compress it somehow. I thought of using the technique Jose advised here: [Steps to compress a file using Huffman Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689090/steps-to-compress-a-file-using-huffman-code) but if I take a quick look I can understand pretty quickly that it does not compress the file, but in-fact does the opposite.

Creating a huffman tree may very well be 'out of my league' when we're speaking about skills in programming and specifically in the Assembly Language.
Any ideas to compress data in a more efficient way than ASCII (8*number of letters, lets say for abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz = 208bits).

Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Huffman coding isn't super complicated. However, you might indeed be advised to choose a different project if you have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: @fuz it does require you to make a tree, which I have no experience in making in any language. All the information about trees in the internet does not apply to assembly language bascially

Comment: Do you want an advice on implementing the Huffman code in assembly or in implementing any compressing algorithm?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I thought of implementing the Huffman code, but that seems to be 'out of my league' as I mentioned before. Therefore, I'm currently looking for advice on implementing any compressing algorithm

Comment: The easiest I can think of is [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Not very efficient but it saved my day in more than one occasion.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I thought of putting it that way: lets say the frequency goes like this: a -11, m - 8, c - 3, d - 1, t - 1, q - 1, s - 1, o - 1, p -1. A gets the code 10 and m gets the code 100 and so on until we get to seven times zero (to s at this example), we go back to normal ascii. so what we have done, is compress the 7 most used letters, in order to compress as much data as possible in this way, and not to 'un-compress- the data in some cases like abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz where the z gets 27(!!) bits instead of 8 in ascii.